# Populate a javascript variable check for undefined variables?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a bunch of markers out of a db with PHP and depending on their type i place them in an overlay. But when an overlay doesn't have any markers my code doesn't work.

```
var overlays = {
                    "Markers 1": markers1,
                    "Markers 2": markers2,
                    "Markers 3": markers3,
                    "Markers 4": markers4
                    };
```

For instance my current sql query doesn't return any markers of type 3 and i get the error message:

```
 markers3 is not defined
```

What would be the right way to setup the variable overlay?

[edit]
I am using a simple php/mysql loop to get each marker type

```
 if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
        $return .= "\r\nvar markers".$typeID['typeID']." = L.featureGroup();\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: Where are the markers being defined, or loaded. Put that code in

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're populating markers by echoing them in php. Replace the "Default" values with whatever object you want as follows.

```
var overlays = {
                    "Markers 1": typeof(markers1)==="undefined"? "Default": markers1,
                    "Markers 2": typeof(markers2)==="undefined"? "Default2": markers2,
                    "Markers 3": typeof(markers3)==="undefined"? "Default3": markers3,
                    "Markers 4": typeof(markers4)==="undefined"? "Default4": markers4
                    };
```